# How can split integer based on array keys and after that add values based on that how i split that integer

Tags: php, arrays

I have array $money where key is money's value but array key is - how much that type of money there are.
Here is example :

```
  $money = [
    1 => 5,
    2 => 2,
    5 => 1,
    10 => 4,
    20 => 2,
    50 => 3,
    100 => 1,
    200 => 1
];
```

where  1 = 0.1EUR, 2 = 0.2EUR and so go on till 200 where 200 =  2EUR. Key values are - how much coins i have.
After i'm getting exchange - itneger  95 and i need to split it up based on array keys, show how much and what kind of coins im getting and put those coins back in array.

I tried this way, but programm gives me back only 1 piece of every coin type if it is <= change

```
   if ($change > 0) {
      echo 'Your change is : '. $change;
      foreach (array_reverse($money, true) as $key => $amount) {
          if ($key <= $change) {
              echo 'Returned coin: ' . $key . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

And here is output where you can see that expected output is 95 but programm gives me 88

```
    In progress
    ***
    Your change is : 95
    Returned coin: 50
    Returned coin: 20
    Returned coin: 10
    Returned coin: 5
    Returned coin: 2
    Returned coin: 1
```

expected output would be:

```
    In progress
    ***
    Your change is : 95
    Returned coin: 1 x 50
    Returned coin: 2 x 20
    Returned coin: 1 x 5
```

something like that and after add them to my money array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. You have to bare in mind it is possible to return a specific coin `$amount` times. So I added another loop to do so. You will have to keep track of the current remaining value though.

```
$change = 95;
$rest = $change;

foreach (array_reverse($money, true) as $key => $amount) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
    if ($key <= $rest) {
      echo 'Returned coin: ' . $key . PHP_EOL;
      $rest -= $key;
    }
  }
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/2l16n).

### Alternative

Calculate in advance how many `$key` (current coin value) fit in `$rest` (remaining value).

```
foreach (array_reverse($money, true) as $key => $amount) {
  if ($key <= $rest) {
    $times = floor($rest / $key);
    echo sprintf('Returned coin: %u x %u', $times, $key) . PHP_EOL;
    $rest -= $key * $times;
  }
}
```

### Output

```
Your change is : 95
Returned coin: 1 x 50
Returned coin: 2 x 20
Returned coin: 1 x 5
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/EAo0Q).

Comment: thank you good sir! You helped me a lot :)